# Why are these present perfect?

Tags: tense

> From you **have I been** [A] absent in the spring,
>  When
>   proud-pied April dress'd in all his trim
>   **Hath put** [A’] a spirit of youth in every thing
>  That heavy Saturn **laugh'd and leap'd** [B] with him.
>  Yet nor the lays of
>   birds nor the sweet smell
>  Of different flowers in odor and in
>   hue
>  Could make me any summer's story tell.
>  Or from their
>   proud lap pluck them while they grew;
>  Nor did I wonder at the
>   lily's white,
>  Nor praise the deep vermilion in the rose;
>   They were but sweet, but figures of delight;
>  Drawn after you, you
>   pattern of all those.
>  Yet seem'd it winter still, and, you
>   away,
>  As with your shadow I with these did play.
>  (Virginia
>   Woolf, To the Lighthouse, p.132; Sonnet 98, [William Shakespeare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_98))

The present perfect ([A] and [A’]) seems not refer to the past Reference Time [B]. I guess the present perfects are selected to say the gloomy away from you has lasted till now. Is this right?

Comment: The question concerns an EME use which is no longer current. I recommend migration to ELU.

Comment: @StoneyB I checked with ELU mods and migration has been denied.

Comment: Do not try to infer modern English usage from William Shakespeare. 'Twill not serve thee well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reflects usage at a time before the line between past and present perfect was as clearly drawn as it is now in formal usage. Shakespeare employs the present perfect intially to portray what he is telling as a present memory, before moving into the past for the rest.

In fact, this kind of movement from perfect into past is still very frequently encountered in colloquial registers:

> I've been in Washington in the springtime, when the cherries were blooming, and it was a very pretty sight.

Even in formal usage it would be acceptable if only the **first**, opening verb were in the present perfect, and not the verb at the start of the second line. But today we would ordinarily cast all of these in the simple past.

Comment: Might there also be a general truth as well, that poets don't always follow strict grammatical rules, but instead bend them to fit for the sake of rhythm and rhyme? Some of the most egregious examples off the top of my head come from some of old hymns, like, _"He lives, He lives, salvation to impart!"_ (I often cringed at that awful wording, but I suppose Ackley wanted to force the rhyme with _heart_ in the next line.)